# Sending emails with ThreadPool (low efficiency)

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, threadpool, windows-forms-designer

I want to send email messages quick and i use Thread Pool. But, i count the time taking to sent ten emails with thread pool and the time taking to sent ten emails serial (in a for each loop) and the time is the same. What is the problem with my code?

My thread pool code:

```
private sub mymethod()
    addr.Add("first address")
    addr.Add("second address")
    addr.Add("third address")

    addr.Add("tenth address")


    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(20, 20)
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(15, 15)

    start = Date.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds
    For Each add As Object In addr

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf SendMail, add) 

    Next
   End Sub

     Private Sub SendMail(ByVal add As Object)
    If add Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Empty arg!!")
    End If

    Dim client As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient()
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    client.Port = "587"
    client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("address", "password")
    client.EnableSsl = True


    Using Mail As New MailMessage
        Mail.Subject = "test"
        Mail.To.Add(add)
        Mail.From = New MailAddress("address")
        Mail.Body = "body"
        client.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1 

        Try
            client.Send(Mail)
        Catch ex As SmtpException
        Finally
             count += 1
            SendCompleted() 
        End Try
    End Using

End Sub

 Private Sub SendCompleted()

    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf SendCompleted))
        Return
    End If

    If (count = addr.Count) Then

        end_ = Date.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds

        label1.Text = (end_ - start)
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the SetMin and SetMaxThreads commands. Does it change anything? BTW: Its always a good idea to let the CLR make decisions about how many threads to use or not. Except you know EXACTLY what you do.

Comment: ok i tried, but nothing changes..

Comment: Shouldn't this post be on Code Review?